# Domain returns timeout

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, subdomain, external-ip

I'm trying to associate a sub-domain that I have on the IP of a server that is running an api on IIS, the server is on AWS lightsail.

On lightsail I set IP to static, this IP I can access the api, but through my sub-domain I can't... DNS is configured on the provider with:

- A record, targeted sub-domain for IPv4;
- AAAA record, targeted sub-domain for IPv6.

Still on lightsail I released ports 80 and 443.

The message that appears in the browser is (www2) took too long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Images:

- IIS Binding

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Domain Provider

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Chrome (sub-domain)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Chrome (Static IP)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Have you tried using nslookup to see if the IP is actually associated?

Comment: Is the subdomain accessed over HTTP or HTTPS? Is the base domain HSTS enabled with `includeSubdomains`?

Comment: the error was on my internet service provider, I gave the tracert and it started to timeout when I went through the service provider, I called it, I explained to them what I needed and in a few days it was released...

Answer (score 0):

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` indicates this isn't a DNS problem (unless your DNS is pointing at the wrong place).

You will usually get a name not resolved type error if your DNS isn't working.

Nevertheless it isn't a bad idea to do

`dig @1.1.1.1 A www2.example.com AAAA www2.example.com`

and verify they are pointing at the correct ipv4/6 addresses.

If DNS is pointing to the correct IPs, then this is an issue with firewall or IIS.

You can use `nmap` to do a quick port scan of your IP and see if ports 80 and 443 are open.

If the ports appear open and the IP is right...then it is likely an IIS or application config issue.  For instance...very often in virtual hosting environments, a server may not respond/handle a request if it isn't configured to recognize the hostname.